# Why is ternary operator ignoring condition order?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I was studying about ternary operation nesting and made some tests with this routine:

```
<?php

$test1 = [15,30,'ok'];
$test2 = [8,90,'fail'];
$test3 = [4,32,'ok'];

$test1[2] == 'ok' ?
    print('First passed. The second round marks '.
            $test2[1]/$test2[0] < 10 ? 'an irrelevant value' : $test2[1]/$test2[0].
            ' and the third was skipped.') :
    print('First failed. The second round was skipped and the third marks '.
            $test3[1]/$test3[0] < 10 ? 'an irrelevant value' : $test3[1]/$test3[0]);
```

Although I know why it's not printing the string in the way I'd expect (it ignores everything before conditional test) because it lacks parenthesis around the ternary operator, it's showing some curious behavior despite of that. It's inverting the operator's evaluation priority.

#### Example

This test, written as it is, should return `11.25` since `11.25 > 10`, but instead it returns `an irrelevant value`!

If I change the `<` operator for `>`, it should then print `an irrelevant value`, since it's `true`, but it evaluates to `false` and print `11.25` anyway.

Can anyone explain to me why it happens? Like I've said, I **know** the above statement is syntactically wrong, but I'm willing to understand why it alters the way PHP works the logic.

Comment: Parens. Division and comparison have a higher [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `?:`

Comment: I believe that the above comments should be placed in an answer. You guys are not part of the *Try this Elite Club* ;-) Edit: Mark deleted his comment.

Comment: No idea why the question was downvoted, I found it to be interesting.

Comment: This is *exactly* why you shouldn't nest ternary operations.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, it isn't.

Comment: ^ Explain why then @melpomene - there is a fairly cardinal rule about nesting ternary operators, unspoken though it is.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The outer ternaries aren't part of the problem. You can simply remove them. The issue is  `.` vs `<` vs `?:` - no nesting involved. Also, in this case the ternaries aren't even directly nested: `X ? print(Y) : print(Z)` - `Y` and `Z` happen to contain ternaries, but there's no confusion possible because of the parens.

Comment: I *know* the problem is the precedence operators. Nesting masks the problem @melpomene .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php lists the PHP operators with their precedence. According to this table,

```
'First passed. The second round marks ' . $test2[1] / $test2[0] < 10
    ? 'an irrelevant value'
    : $test2[1] / $test2[0] . ' and the third was skipped.'
```

parses as

```
(('First passed. The second round marks ' . ($test2[1] / $test2[0])) < 10)
    ? 'an irrelevant value'
    : (($test2[1] / $test2[0]) . ' and the third was skipped.')
```

- `/` binds tighter than `.`
- `.` binds tighter than `<`
- `<` binds tighter than `?:`

In other words, you're comparing the string `'First passed. The second round marks 11.25'` to the number `10`.

Comment: Precedence always gets me by the feet. Thank you very much!